# No segues on UIViewController created programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I am on VC `A`, I go to vc `B` programatically and then VC `B` has no segues to go to VC `C` (`perform(segueWithIdentifier:)`crashes).
But if I go to VC `B` using a segue, I can then call the segue to go to VC `C`.

Here is my code that crashes:

VC `A`:

```
// Method A (that does not crash)
// self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoB", sender: self)

// Method B (that crashes)
let dst = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcB")
if let navigator = navigationController {
    navigator.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

VC `B`:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoC", sender: self) // crashes here
```

The thing is that i want to be able to reach VC `B` from anywhere, hence the programatic push using the navigation controller. I'd like to understand why this happens and how to achieve what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Are you register segue identifier "gotoC" once check it

Comment: What is the crash log ?

Comment: @srinivasn Yes i have the segue `gotoC` because it works when I use a segue to go from `A` to `B`. However, it crashes when I push `B` using the `navigationControler`.

Comment: @NiravD It says that the segue was not found (eventhough it exists on my storyboard).

Comment: @Dliix Check one thing that destination of segue `gotoB` and storyboardIdentifier of that controller is `vcB` or something else.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reach this VC from everywhere, you have to rather instantiate it from storyboard programmatically and then present / push it. Something like this:

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle(for: self))

   let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewControllerId")

   navigationController.push(viewController, animated: true)
```

Make sure to set StoryboardID in your Storyboard for this view controller

Comment: Thank for your quick answer, however, this is what I am doing at the moment. But when I use this method, the createViewController has no segues and thus `perform(segueWithIdentifier:) ` crashes. I don't know why. Creating a VC via the storyboard should link all segues right ?

Comment: you don't have to use segues at all

Comment: yes I do because the vc `B` redirects to a vc `C` from another project and it uses segues. I can not change this behaviour eventhough I'd like to.